# are hypothesis test distributions empirical or theoretical?

Tags: statistics

In all hypothesis tests, you end up with a test statistic that follows a specific distribution, and you have to decide on a probability based on that.

My question is: how do we know that a given statistic follows a given distribution?

- was the distribution created to fit experimental results
- or is the distribution directly derived from theory

I'm asking because, contrary to some probability distributions (eg. binomial, geometric) which are directly derived from probability rules, for test statistic distributions most textbooks just state the fact (at least, most textbooks I have seen).

Where do the $t$, $F$ and $\chi^2$ distributions come from?

Comment: Some of them are definitely derived from theory. The sampling distribution of the mean, given certain conditions, is a normal or a $t;$ that fact is either the Central Limit Theorem, or was proved by the Guiness beer guy (Called himself "Student"). I don't know about all of them, but I imagine a good many of those are proven from theory.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: thanks. that is exactly where I started wondering. the central limit theorem can be proved, but the transition to $t$ distribution (and the conditions needed) are a bit fuzzy on most resources

Comment: Right, the $t$ distribution is a crazy complicated distribution, and the proof, I'm sure, is rather complex. I'm pretty sure it's been done, though.